# How to recode dataset based on the values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big dataset with its format being similar to the followings:

```
names <- c('s1','s2','s3', 's4', 's5','s6', 's7', 's8','s9')
metals <- c(4.2, 5.3, 5.4,6, 7,8.5,0, 10.1,11)
plastics <- c(5.1, 0, 2.4,6.1, 7.7,5.5,1.99, 0 ,2.5)
grade<- c("AA", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AC" , "AB", NA , NA, NA)
my_df <- data.frame(names, metals, plastics, grade )
```

I need to recode each column For numeric columns I need to assign 1 where the value is greater than 0 and for the "grade" columns lets assume I want AA=1, AB=2, AC=3. what is the most efficient way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this one is the most efficient one, but we can use `recode` in `car` package for the character column.

```
my_df$metals <- ifelse (my_df$metals > 0, 1 , 0)

my_df$plastics <- ifelse (my_df$plastics > 0, 1 , 0)

library(car)
my_df$grade<-recode(my_df$grade, "'AA'=1; 'AB'='2'; 'AC'='3'")
```

Output

```
names metals plastics grade
1    s1      1        1     1
2    s2      1        0     2
3    s3      1        1     2
4    s4      1        1     2
5    s5      1        1     3
6    s6      1        1     2
7    s7      0        1  <NA>
8    s8      1        0  <NA>
9    s9      1        1  <NA>
```

Comment: For your second part, you could also just overwrite the levels - `levels(my_df$grade) <- c(1,2,3)`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - probably preferable to keep it as numbers, so yeah, good point. Also, `c(1,2,3)[my_df$grade]`

Comment: Can I do all at once if I had lots of numeric columns and the coding patterns were similar for all?

Comment: @Jack - see Osssan's answer below and my comment.

Comment: How would the code change if I wanted plastic column to be coded like this: 0-3 <- 1, 3-6<- 2, 6-9<-3 , greater than 9 <- 4

Comment: We can use package car again  my_df$plastic <- with(my_df, recode(plastic, "0:3=1; 3:6=2; 6:9=3, else=4"))

Answer (score 2):

As always in R, there are a million ways to do even the simplest task. Here's 2 more:

```
numvars <- sapply(my_df, is.numeric)
my_df[numvars] <- lapply(my_df[numvars], findInterval, 1)


my_df$grade <- c(2,1,3)[match(my_df$grade, c("AB","AA","AC"))]
               #newvals                    #oldvals

#  names metals plastics grade
#1    s1      1        1     1
#2    s2      1        0     2
#3    s3      1        1     2
#4    s4      1        1     2
#5    s5      1        1     3
#6    s6      1        1     2
#7    s7      0        1    NA
#8    s8      1        0    NA
#9    s9      1        1    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply` for numeric columns and `match` for character column

**Edited** as per@thelatemail's comments to avoid intermediate matrix coercion

```
my_df[,sapply(my_df,is.numeric)] = lapply(my_df[,sapply(my_df,is.numeric)],function(x) ifelse(x>0,1,0))

my_df$grade = match(my_df$grade,c("AA","AB","AC"))

my_df
#  names metals plastics grade
#1    s1      1        1     1
#2    s2      1        0     2
#3    s3      1        1     2
#4    s4      1        1     2
#5    s5      1        1     3
#6    s6      1        1     2
#7    s7      0        1    NA
#8    s8      1        0    NA
#9    s9      1        1    NA
```

There will be other solutions using data.table,dplyr soon. You could use `microbenchmark` to choose the best solution

Comment: Hint - use `lapply` instead of `apply` - `my_df[,sapply(my_df,is.numeric)] <- lapply(my_df[,sapply(my_df,is.numeric)], FUN=function(x) ifelse(x>0,1,0))` it will avoid coercion to a matrix.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @MFR's answer, here are two ways to do it:

```
NumColsToReplace = c("metals", "plastics")
my_df[NumColsToReplace] = ifelse(my_df[NumColsToReplace] > 0, 1, 0)
```

This allows you to pre-specify the columns you want to replace without copying the second line a bunch of times.

There is also another more efficient way using `lapply` and `replace`:

```
my_df[NumColsToReplace] = lapply(my_df[NumColsToReplace], 
                                 function(x) replace(x, x>0, 1))
```

This may be more typing, but it is two times as fast (or more) as the first method. Below are some benchmarking:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                                   expr      min
 lapply(my_df[NumColsToReplace], function(x) replace(x, x > 0,      1))     23.949
                                  ifelse(my_df[NumColsToReplace] > 0, 1, 0) 59.445
     lq     mean median     uq     max neval
 26.515 29.92362 28.654 30.364  57.306   100
 62.438 68.84436 63.721 73.129 159.515   100
```

So depending on how large your dataframe is. You way want to consider the second method.

`levels(my_df$grade) <- c(1,2,3)` to recode grade mentioned by @thelatemail seems to be the most efficient.